# SSIS Data Source Name Change

Tags: ssis, bids

I have about 30 SSIS jobs in a solution, and they all use a common data source which is named ProjectDBDev, but I want to change this to be ProjectDB, dropping the DEV part.  I didn't want to blindly do this and find I need to alter the references for all packages, or have more serious issues. Can anyone see any issue with doing this?

Comment: All project is in a single xml file. You can modify xml from visual studio or close it and replace name with your favorite text editor. Be careful, you will found this identifier at several levels. Disclaimer: make a backup copy of your project before this.

Comment: I have edited the connection strings via the XML before, but I will give this a go also - I will backup to make sure though, thanks.